# Dictionary is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I design a very simple code inside a file called t1.py

```
stuff = {'ball':1, 'club':2}
print stuff
```

So when i do, python t1.py it displays the dictionary properly no errors, but if i go into the python interpreter and type:
. >>> import t1

and then i type: print stuff

i get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'stuff' is not defined

I need to declare a dictinary so i can use it further ahead in the code.

Comment: try `print t1.stuff` or `from t1 import stuff` and then `print stuff`

Comment: or ``from t1 import stuff``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stuff` is defined inside `t1`. You've imported t1, so you need to print `t1.stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `from  t1 import *` then you can use `print (stuff)`.

If you write `import t1` you have to use it like `print (t1.stuff)`

Also you can import it like `import t1 as something` and `print (something.stuff)`